# Replace array values with corrections?

Tags: php, str-replace

This should be easy.

I have an **$array**.

some of the values of which are **$wrong** (second array)

so I want to change them for their **$corrections** (third array)

I was using this:

```
$corrected = str_replace($wrong, $corrections, $array);
```

But realized that it was replacing letters instead of taking into account the hole value of each array.

So if $corrections contained "i" as a value, it would replace every single letter "i" instead of only the value from $wrong which is equal to "i".

Whats the correct function for replacing one array with another as per corrections?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just make $wrong['someValue'] = $corrections['someValue']; ?

Comment: You would need to give examples of your arrays and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the arrays and check the words as a whole:

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    foreach($wrongs as $key => $wrong) {
        if($item === $wrong) {
            $item = $corrections[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we're passing the `$item` to be corrected in the original array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

This also assumes that the `$wrong` array correlates 1 to 1 with the `$corrections` array... so be sure the two match up!

Comment: Isn't there a way to contrast two arrays without having to LOOP through all the values?